# Nginx не загружается файл на сервер

Tags: php, apache, nginx, config, configuration

Поставил на сервер nginx в довесок к apache, чтобы отдавать статику. Перестали загружаться файлы на сервер. В скрипте элементарно пустой `$_FILES`.

**UPD.** nginx версии 1.2.1. Картинка шлется POST запросом во фрейм, чтобы не обновлять страницу. Мало ли, может как-нибудь влияет. Но если заходить на сайт по порту 8080(то есть апачевскому), то файл загружается.

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;
events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1280;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;

    server {
        listen 80 default;
        server_name site.ru;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_connect_timeout 120;
            proxy_send_timeout 120;
            proxy_read_timeout 180;
        }

        location ~* \.(png|gif)$ {
            root /var/www/main_user/data/www/site.ru/;
            access_log off;
            expires 3d;
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                expires 10m;
                rewrite ^/skin/(.+)\.png$ /skin.php?i=$1&r=1 break;
                rewrite ^/skin/(.+)\.gif$ /skin.php?i=$1&r=1 break;
            }
            error_page 404 = @fallback;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;  
        }

        location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|xml|docx|xlsx|woff)$ {
            root /var/www/main_user/data/www/site.ru/;
            access_log off;
            expires 3d;
            error_page 404 = @fallback;
            proxy_cache_valid 404 1m;  
        }

        location @fallback {
            proxy_pass http://site.ru:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: мб где-то `proxy_pass_request_body off` в инклудах

Comment: вы сэкономите себе кучу нервов, если будете пользоваться только одним сервером

Comment: Я с удовольствием оставил бы только один nginx. Но это пока не представляется возможным.

Comment: ограничения по телу запроса есть и на уровне apache и на уровне php

Comment: Если я зайду на сайт по порту апача (минуя nginx), то файлы успешно загружаются.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` явно указал временную папку `upload_tmp_dir = /tmp`.
Права папке и владельца выставил те, от кого запущен nginx (в моем случае www-data).

Теперь в `$_FILES` видны файлы.